# Login username/password for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

I registered for SO with Google quick login, but now I want to use a separate login username/password, is this possible? I tried going to manage logins > more login methods, but I couldn't find this option.

Comment: I did this myself by using a different OpenID provider.  Do you have a Yahoo email address?

Comment: I don't know why you would want a second login option when you already have a perfectly good one with google, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: @SamIam a 2nd login is smart for everyone.  If your OpenId provider decides to shut down unexpectedly or stop supporting OpenId ([hey Look, Google decided to stop supporting OpenId](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) - although it still works for existing sites for now), a 2nd method to log in would help

Comment: Did you check [My How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)? Following the "Add more logins" link offers 7 different login providers (I just checked and counted them).

Comment: Thanks robert and ken for those suggestions I was hoping for a direct SO login. And of course thanks psub :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Technically, Stack Overflow does not have a dedicated login system. They have chosen to support [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) (and [OAuth 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) on a few places). Given Google has [deprecated OpenID in favor of OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID), I am assuming that OAuth will become more supported on Stack Exchange sites.

However, Stack Exchange does have their own OpenID endpoint, so in a sense, that is the closest to a dedicated Stack Overflow login.

You are on the right path when you went to your profile, clicked Settings, clicked "My Logins", and once there, you can click on "add more logins". However, the option to add a Stack Exchange login appears to have gone missing. I've opened a bug report on MSE, [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol).

In the meantime, you should be able to add the URL for the Stack Exchange OpenID into the URL field from the "add more logins" screen:

> [image]

The URL for the SE OpenID is https://openid.stackexchange.com/ so just copy and paste this into that URL field and you will be taken to a page where you can login if you have an OpenID already or sign up for a new one.

Comment: Thank you so much for an in-depth reply, filing the bug, and most of all telling me I was in the right direction :) Its nice haha nice change in place of people saying "go bak and make an effort first loser" haha. Also +1 to your comment on the guy re second login. :) PS nice hand writing on that image "url here" :P hhaa

Comment: @Noitidart another option would be to log out completely and sign up again.  When you do that, the SE option is there.  You can create a brand new account, then add your Google account to that account.  That will trigger a merge and you'll have your brand new account associated with your current account.

Comment: I tried it man :( I had to use another email and then when I tried adding my google quick login so it would trigger merge, it keeps saying it belongs to another account "Noitidart" and says "Login is as noitidart or cancel to stay logged in as my new account"

Comment: @Noitidart if it isn't working, then just follow the process outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).  You want your new SE account to be the "merge keep" account and your old Google account to be the "merge delete".