# Add password to my account

Tags: support, login

I made registration on Stack Overflow using my google account.

How can i Log In to Stack Overflow using email/password?

In my profile I can't find how can i add password to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You log with google plus and then click in you profile (avatar) now go to  settings > My logins > add more logins.
In this option you can add more logins and remove others.

[image]

Comment: on page "add more logins…" have OpenID, Google, Facebook and some other social services but no way to create "email/password"

Comment: now you should use openID with email and password:
http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/

Comment: i found this reply tag http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261729/4693765

Comment: There seems to be a bug with the password maker... if you use something like `gaskdfhalkhfweifhalihfliaweuhfajfpweofjeofj` it will think it's not strong enough and silently fail, despite having crazy amounts of entropy.