# Stack Overflow login vs user accounts

Tags: discussion, login, accounts, email, google

I created my Stack Overflow account a while back using a login from my work email (stupid, I know). Now that I'm at another job, I went to change things around. I updated my email setting to be my Gmail account.  I can log in via the Google+ button.

However, if I put my Gmail address in, the login page claims there is no account with that email address. I am now unable to use the "work" email address (even though I still know the password for Stack Overflow - the actual email address doesn't exist anymore).

I don't like having to connect via "social media" when accessing Stack Overflow, as that's primarily for work.

Is there any way to get my account to use the email address that I've provided and allow me to set a password for it?

Also, why does my old work email still, apparently, have an account associated with it?

The mylogins page doesn't seem to have a way to set a user specified email / password. Nor does it have a way to pick your Gmail account (except to use your Gmail password).

Comment: Did you change it via "Edit Profile & Settings" > "Edit Profile"? (This isn't fully clear through your post- If you added it through "My Logins" then it should be working properly, but changing it through "Edit Profile" doesn't change your login details.)

Comment: Yes I did.   In the Private information section there is an email field.   That isn't the log-in email address.   In some of the other preference settings you can set the email that your daily comments and such get sent to, again, not your login email.

Comment: Stack Exhange login works off Open Id- Except for the Google login, there's some weird workaround for that. To change your _login_ email, you go to "My Logins" (which you've already found) and click "add more logins..." to get the screen to add it. Clicking Google+ allows you to use your gmail account (not _just_ a Google+ account) to connect to Stack Exchange. Alternatively, you can use a Yahoo! email account (which is what I use.) if you have one set up, or just set one up specifically for Stack Exchange. If you _want_ a dedicated Stack Exchange login (cont)

Comment: I went to the password recovery "forgot password?" link thing in the Join SO area and requested a reset.   It recognized the gmail email in that link.   I got email, it says, "This email address is associated with an account, but no password is associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in."   There is a link below it to create a password, which I guess is the solution.

Comment: (cont) you can follow the steps [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255394/cannot-add-stack-exchange-openid-login?rq=1) (Note that the link to set it up is in the question itself.)

Comment: That will most probably create you a Stack Exchange Open Id, yes.

Comment: I hate to answer my own questions, but what I was looking to do was associate a new email with my account and the path to do that seems to be through the forgot? link in the login.    Interestingly, the old email, which isn't associated anymore, when I sign in, it now attempts to create a new account(which I cancelled), so it must be fully disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the email via settings and/or MyLogins, you are not prompted to enter a password.   Until the password is associated, SO treats it like its an invalid email.   It doesn't transfer your old password over to the new email address.

So, click the "forgot?" link under the password and put in the new email address.   It will send you an email to tell you that you need to set the original password for that email and it sends you a link to do just that.

Click the link and set your password.  Now your new email login will work just fine.

Comment: Note that if you get "This email address is associated with an account, but no password is associated with it yet..." message in you mail-box, you can create username/password for Stack Overflow by following  psubsee2003's answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261739/164680.